# Как вызвать метод pm_power_off() из ядра linux?

Tags: linux, c, kernel

Есть метод в ядре для отключения питания:

```
static void native_machine_power_off(void)
{
  if (pm_power_off) {
    if (!reboot_force)
      machine_shutdown();
    pm_power_off();
  }
  /* A fallback in case there is no PM info available */
  tboot_shutdown(TB_SHUTDOWN_HALT);
}
```

Как его вызвать и чем?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, речь идёт о *`/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c`*. В исходниках ядра вы можете увидеть структуру [`machine_ops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L731) (ссылка для 4.19.2):

```
struct machine_ops machine_ops __ro_after_init = {
    .power_off = native_machine_power_off,
    .shutdown = native_machine_shutdown,
    .emergency_restart = native_machine_emergency_restart,
    .restart = native_machine_restart,
    .halt = native_machine_halt,
#ifdef CONFIG_KEXEC_CORE
    .crash_shutdown = native_machine_crash_shutdown,
#endif
};
```

И в этом же файле находится доступная для использования функция `machine_power_off`, которая вызывает функцию, упомянутую вами:

```
void machine_power_off(void)
{
    machine_ops.power_off();
}
```

Попробуйте использовать её.